# I want to sum same column in 4 different tables mysql

Tags: mysql, join, sum, union

I have 4 tables with different columns. But in 4 tables i have two common columns.one Vendor_id and Stock.This Vendor_id can repeat in all the 4 tables.
Now ny requirement is i want to sum all the stocks related to all the vendor ids in all the 4 tables. For example :

**Table One**

```
+----------+-------------+
|vendor_id | stoclk      | 
+----------+-------------+
| 1234    | 75.00        | 
+----------+-------------+
| 1234    | 75.00        | 
+----------+-------------+
| 789      | 75.00       | 
+----------+-------------+
```

**Table Two**

```
+----------+-------------+
|vendor_id | stoclk      | 
+----------+-------------+
| 1234     | 5.00        | 
+----------+-------------+
| 2389     | 15.00       | 
+----------+-------------+
| 789      | 15.00       | 
+----------+-------------+
```

**My deisred out put will be**

```
+----------+-------------+
|vendor_id | stoclk      | 
+----------+-------------+
| 1234     | 155.00      | 
+----------+-------------+
| 2389     | 15.00       | 
+----------+-------------+
| 789      | 90.00       | 
+----------+-------------+
```

For this i used below query.

```
    SELECT vendor_id,SUM(stock) FROM (
          SELECT vendor_id, stock FROM hs_tab1
          UNION ALL
          SELECT vendor_id, stock FROM hs_tab2
          UNION ALL
     )a
```

But i am getting only one vendor id and total number or stocks like this

```
   +----------+-------------+
   |vendor_id | stoclk      | 
   +----------+-------------+
   | 1234     | 260.00      | 
   +----------+-------------+
```

Please tell me some one where i am doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure but may be `group by` will help you. Just give a try

Comment: Why these four separate tables?  Sounds like poor database design to me.

Comment: You use aggregate function 'sum' without 'group' operator, it's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT vendor_id,SUM(stock) 
FROM ( SELECT vendor_id, stock FROM hs_tab1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT vendor_id, stock FROM hs_tab2
     )a
GROUP BY vendor_id;
```